Spike in MongoDb connections when using lambda tmp storage for logs
import logging
import json

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class LogContext:
    def __init__(self, file_path='/tmp/log.json'):
        self.log_array = []
        self.file_path = file_path

    def log_helper(self, **kwargs):
        log = {k: self._custom_serialize(v) for k, v in kwargs.items()}
        self.log_array.append(log)
        self._write_to_file()

    def _custom_serialize(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return {k: self._custom_serialize(v) for k, v in value.items()}
        elif callable(value):
            return value.__name__
        else:
            return value

    def _write_to_file(self):
        with open(self.file_path, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(self.log_array, file, indent=4,default=str)

log_context = LogContext('/tmp/log.json')

def log_helper(**kwargs):
    # log_context.log_helper(**kwargs)

This is how I am saving logs in my AWS Lambda. This works perfectly, but for no reason at all, I am seeing a spike in the number of connections. Any possible reasons?

def get_db():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(os.environ["MONGODB_URI"])
    log_helper(**{"log_name": "getMongoDBClient", "get_client_result": client})
    db = client[os.environ["MONGO_DB_NAME"]]
    return db

This is MongoDB connection code.
